# Removing descriptor from Returned Value

Tags: zapier

I am working inside Zapier with their javascript code action. I have built the following code to match and return values based on form submission data and now need to remove the "Text:" identifier at the beginning to make it more human readable. Important to note, the RegEx lookup including the identifier of /text:\s is necessary to only grab the selected values of the checkbox list from the form response data.

```
var svcs = inputData.addrSvcs.match(/text:\s(NCOA|Return Service Requested|Address Service Requested|None)/gi);
return svcs.map(function(svc) {
  if (svcs) {
  console.log(svcs);
    return {value: svcs};
  }});

//returns text: NCOA, text: Return Service Requested, text: Address Service Requested, text: None
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking to do something similar with Code in Zapier, the following seems to give the output I needed.

```
var addrSvc = inputData.addrSvcs.match(/text:\s(NCOA|Return Service Requested|Address Service Requested|None)/gi);
return addrSvc.map(function(svc) {
  if (addrSvc) {
    var originalTxt = addrSvc.join(',');
    var newText = originalTxt.replace(/text:\s/gi,'')
    return {addrServices: newText};
  }});
```